# Detecting shift/command click on Chrome browser action button

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to detect a shift-click or command-click on a browser action button in the chrome bar?

For example, the following code does not work:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(e) {
    console.log(e.shiftKey) // is undefined
});
```

Comment: I believe I've found a way to do this. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682851/capturing-a-modified-click-on-the-extension-toolbar-icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682851/capturing-a-modified-click-on-the-extension-toolbar-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not provided by the API. You can't detect modifiers, or different mouse buttons.

Chrome API events are not DOM events, looking for `e` parameter won't help. Each event has its own list of parameters passed to the callback; look it up in the documentation.

In case of the [`browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked):

> The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:
>
> ```
> function(tabs.Tab tab) {...};
> ```
>
> [`tabs.Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab)   `tab`

So the only information you get is the current tab at the time the button was clicked.

Comment: Filed feature request https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=475339. Thanks!

Comment: @Brad I don't think you're the first, I think there is a duplicate already

Comment: Looks like I was actually.

Comment: Yeah, I only found a related bug. I did remember it existed - but it wasn't the focus of the bug. You saw me point out a comment.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a way to accomplish this.  In my case, I needed to detect a `ctrl-click` and a `ctrl-alt-click` event on the toolbar icon.

Apparently the background script cannot capture keyboard events, but the content script can.  So I set an event listener in the content script to listen for `ctrl` and `alt` keypresses and send a message to the background script.  As it happens, the `keydown` event has boolean properties for `ctrlKey` and `altKey` built in so I did't have to implicitly check the value of the keypress.  In your case, can use the `shiftKey` property.

**content.js**

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
    if(event.ctrlKey){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'ctrlPressed'}, function(){});
    }
    if(event.altKey){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'altPressed'}, function(){});
    }       
});

window.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'keyup'}, function(){});  
});
```

**background.js**

```
var ctrlPressed = false;
var altPressed = false;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    switch(request.type){
        case 'ctrlPressed':
            ctrlPressed = true;
            break;
        case 'altPressed':
            altPressed = true;
            break;
        case 'keyup':
            ctrlPressed = false;
            altPressed = false;
            break;
    }
});
```

Now my `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` can detect a `click`, `double-click`, `ctrl-click`, and `ctrl-alt-click`.  (With just a little more code I could also detect `ctrl-double-click` and `ctrl-alt-double-click`.)  The only caveat is that the active tab must have focus to capture keypresses.  The `window.focus()` line at the end of the routine should handle that.

**background.js**

```
// Listen for toolbar icon clicks
var clickCnt = 0;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    clickCnt++; 
    if(clickCnt > 1){       
        console.log('Double click detected');
        clickCnt = 0;
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }else{                          
        if(ctrlPressed){
            if(altPressed){
                console.log('ctrl-alt-click detected');
            }else{
                console.log('ctrl-click detected');
            }
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function(){  
            console.log('Single click detected');
            clickCnt = 0;
        }, 250);
    }
    window.focus()
});
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but it requires that the currently open tab has your content script injected, and furthermore that the click happened while that tab was in focus (otherwise your modifier information can be stale). You can't always guarantee that, even if you inject it at `<all_urls>`. My answer "API doesn't provide that information" still stands though.